# How to change visibility with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm new to Javascript and since there is no `onclick` for css I need a little help.

This is my html:

```
<div id="dropnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Navigation</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Paintings.html">Paintings</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Bio.html">Bio</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
#dropnav {
position:relative;
z-index:100;
top:-60px;
left:18%;
background-size:18%;

}
#dropnav ul {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

}

#dropnav ul li {
display:inline;
float:left;
width:68.5%;
list-style-type:none;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
font-family:arial;
height:50px;

}

#dropnav ul li a {
background-color:#808080;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:50px;
display:block;
padding-left:36.2%;
width:63.8%;
}

#dropnav ul li a:hover {
background-color:#666666;
}

#dropnav ul li ul li {
width:99.8%;

}
#dropnav ul li ul li a{
background-color:#666666;
}
#dropnav ul li ul li a:hover {
background-color:#333333;

}

#dropnav ul li ul {
visibility:hidden;
}

#dropnav ul li:onclick ul {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Now I need the :onclick to work so if you could fix it that would be great. Thanks for your help

Comment: do you want to make the element visible on when the mouse is pressed? or do you want to toggle the visibility

Comment: Yes I want to make the element visible when it gets clicked

Answer (score 2):

One way to change visibility onclick is by adding an event attribute to your html tag:

```
onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';"
```

For example, here is your navigation bar with disappearing links:

```
<div id="dropnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Navigation</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Paintings.html" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';">Paintings</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Bio.html" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';">Bio</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop this (it's useless):

```
#dropnav ul li:onclick ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Add This:

```
#dropnav ul li.open ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#dropnav ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

Just adding a class, which can be further dealt with in plain CSS. This way your application won't be bound by any strict laws.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure css3 by abusing the :not pseudo class. For example you can trigger an animation after an onclick has happened.

```
 <a href="#" id="btn" onclick="return false">Click</a>

<style>
    #btn:not(:active) {
        /* now keep red background for 1s */
        transition: background-color 1000ms step-end;
    }

    #btn:active {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

Try it - http://jsfiddle.net/WG4Sf/

Here is a good article on CSS click events and if you should use them. http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/click-events/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
document.getElementById("d").style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="change();">Click Me</a><br/>
<div id="d">This is just example</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#dropnav ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('visibility','visible');
})
```

Comment: This would require having jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

`:active` is ur required css property

[WORKING SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T3ecP/1/)

I have just changed the visibility property for my convinience. U can change it to what u need exactly.